# Passing method parameters/arguments to method reference - bind, anonymous, named

Tags: javascript

I have multiple places in my code where i use method references(i.e. just the method  name with no arguments) but I need to pass it specefic arguments.

I don't want to insert an anonymous method b.c. it makes the code unreadable.

I've told I can use the .bind method, but I don't know how to use it properly.  Can some one elaborate on how to do this.

Here is one example of where I need to to to this.

How do I use **bind** to add in parameters to ajax_signin?

```
if(d===0){ajax('arche_model.php',serialize(c)+'&a=signin',ajax_signin,b);}
```

Comment: Which method are you wanting to make smaller here?

Comment: you want to use .bind? or don't want use anonymous methods?

Comment: I would like to use bind in this instance to add parameters to ajax_signin

Comment: Are you passing around method names as strings? Or are you passing around the methods themselves?

Comment: Have you read the tutorial on bind at MDN? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind They have quite a few examples

Comment: @stack.user.1 - when is above script called? on a click of a button? in that case use something like this -
$('#mybutton').bind('click', function() {
  alert('something');
});

Comment: you still use an anonymous method...I don't need bind if I use an anonymous method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `ajax_signin()` to get called with parameters, then you have to make a separate function that you can pass to ajax that calls `ajax_signin()` with the appropriate parameters.  There are a couple ways to do this:

Using an anonymous function:

```
if(d===0){ajax('arche_model.php',serialize(c)+'&a=signin',function() {ajax_signin("parm1","parm2")},b);}
```

Creating your own named function:

```
function mySignIn() {
    ajax_signin("parm1","parm2");
}

if(d===0){ajax('arche_model.php',serialize(c)+'&a=signin',mySignIn,b);}
```

---

If you want to use `.bind()` and you are sure you are only running in browsers that support .bind() or you have a shim to make `.bind()` always work, then you can do something like this:

```
if(d===0){ajax('arche_model.php',serialize(c)+'&a=signin',ajax_signin.bind(this, "parm1","parm2"),b);}
```

The .bind() call creates a new function that always has a specific `this` ptr and always has `"parm1"` and `"parm2"` as it's first two parameters.

Comment: But there should be a way to use bind?

Comment: This is not a good answer, there is a general use answer using partial function application and to manually do this each time would be archaic.

Comment: I added a `.bind()` option to my answer, though I'm not sure how it's any better in this case than the anonymous function option and `.bind()` has browser compatibility issues that you have to plan for.

Comment: @GregAgnew - if you have the same parameters you want to send over and over in multiple places, you simply make one named function and use that everywhere.  `.bind()` is new and not universally supported and doesn't seem like it saves much for this purpose.  Your `partial` solution hardly seems simpler.  I don't see how that's any simpler than creating either a named function or an anonymous function.  The OP can now choose from the three different solutions offered.

Comment: @jfriend00 .bind is only supported in newer browsers, .apply is supported way back. The bigger difference however is that partial allows you to apply a context to the function in an elegant way. The only way for you to do this would be function() {ajax_signin.apply(context,"parm1","parm2")}; Which I think is not very elegant.

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder I guess.  Anonymous functions have been used for years to solve this problem.  They work perfectly fine.  The OP can choose which method they like.

Comment: If bind is not fully suppored I'm just going to use anonymous function call to the function I need with the parameters in it...I know some day I will probably have to update to bind..

Answer (score 0):

You should be using partial function application! IE: The following:

```
// This will call a function using a reference with predefined arguments.
function partial(func, context /*, 0..n args */) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  return function() {
    var allArguments = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    return func.apply(context ? context : this, allArguments);
  };
}
```

The first argument is the function you want to call, the second argument the context, and any arguments after that will be 'pre-loaded' into the function call.

Note: 'Context' is what `this` will refer to once the function is being executed.

Comment: This is similar to what `.bind()` does.  I don't see how it's simpler or more efficient than an anonymous function declaration which has been a tried and true staple of Javascript development for a long time or better than what `.bind()` does.  I'm not saying it won't work - I just don't understand why it's better?

Comment: It is a matter of preference..I think..+ I just want to learn

Comment: Its better beacuse .bind is not supported in older browsers. It is from javascript 1.8.5 where as apply goes back to 1.3 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply